# Azure ML mounted datastore: os.path.exists returns False, but os.makedirs fails because path exists

Tags: azuremlsdk

I have an Azure ML workspace with a datastore (Datastore 1) setup maybe over 2 years ago.
I created a new Azure Storage container and copied everything over from the azure storage container that serves as Datastore 1. Set this up as Datastore 2.

The file hierarchy inside the 2 containers is identical, because it was a recursive ADF copy.

Running the experiment against the 2nd datastore fails because for a particular mounted path `os.path.exists` returns False, but a subsequent call to `os.makedirs` conditioned on `os.path.exists` fails because:

`FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/i...2/azureml/hd_8.._7/mounts/files/azureml_model/csvs/csvs_from_random_split/`

The only warning in the logs, prior to the run is: `datastore.as_mount" is deprecated after version 1.0.69. Please use "file_dataset.as_mount`

Snippet of code more or less:

```py
from azureml.core import RunConfiguration
from azureml.core import Workspace, Datastore, Experiment
from azureml.data import OutputFileDatasetConfig

ws = Workspace.from_config(args.workspace_config)
datastore = Datastore(ws, args.datastore)
root_dir_ref = datastore.as_mount()
output_dir_ref = OutputFileDatasetConfig(destination=(datastore, output_path))

if not os.path.exists(dataset_store): #dataset_store is a path in output_dir_ref
     os.makedirs(dataset_store)
```

Comment: Can you provide me the code you are using?

Comment: Extracting snippets that might be relevant, from our code, and adding to the original post, as it doesn't look good in the comments.